# Docker Ubuntu container installed software gets removed

Tags: ubuntu, docker, container

First time trying Docker and had lots of questions.
Installed Docker with  Ubuntu container. Didn't know it that doesn't come with the basic essential tools like net-tools , vim , nano etc.
Installed the necessary tools that I required, tested whether it works  and call it a day. Today when run the container, it is back to the earlier stage ,, all the installed packages are gone. Is this supposed to happen ? how do I parmanently install packages in the container?

Note: I installed the Docker -CE version with the help of the installation script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking a container for a VM. A container is just a network and filesystem bubble tailored to run a specific process. It comes with all the software dependencies and so only requires a Linux kernel.

A Docker image such as Ubuntu is rarely used plain. You tailor it to your needs using a `Dockerfile` (see the `docker build` command). A Dockerfile is used to:

- install specific software (mostly runtime support) that are useful for the process: `RUN apt-get install python3 python3-pip`, `RUN pip install requests numpy`
- copy specific files (usually, your own code, plus configuration files for your app and your system (for instance, certificates)): `COPY application.py /app/`. These files are frequently kept together with the Dockerfile.
- set the command that is run when the container is launched: `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/python3","/app/application.py"]`

At the end of the `docker build`, you have a runnable docker image that can execute your application.

If you tweak a container, you can save its state as an image using `docker commit`, but it is considered poor practice, since it doesn't ensure reproducibility: if you need to upgrade the software, you normally rebuild the container using the Dockerfile, so you have best make sure that the Dockerfile and its companion files are all you need to build the final container. This also makes the container more difficult to share, you have to export the whole image instead of just sending the Dockerfile and the code/config.

In serious usage, the Dockerfile and its companion files (configuration...) are versioned in a Git repository, and use the executable files that are produced by the integration chain.

Often, some attempt is often made to keep the container as small as possible. There are Docker images of very small footprint distributions. An Ubuntu is a lot of useless baggage and a Debian will usually do just as well. There are also special-purpose images with preinstalled software (Apache, nginx, MySQL...).

Last you can wonder what happens to files created in the container... by default they are local to the container, and lost if the container instance is removed (`docker rm` command). However when launching the container,  you can bind some files/directories of the container to files/directories on the host, and so have persistent storage outside the container. You can also use "volume images".

Containers are very useful, but must be used properly...

Comment: i was under the impression that using a push to dockerhub would at least save installed software like nano. or php. i am required to build the software by hand, so at the moment the only option for me is to write a shellscript that installes php8.2 and extensions, apache2 etc. which is really a pain in the ass. other containers on dockerhub have these things pre-installed, why is my finished project-container that is pushed cleansed of everything i configured

Comment: Tell me the difference between a shell script and a dockerfile...

Comment: not my point here, problem is "layer already exists" - i guess i missed the point of re-tagging stuff and everything went void

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is supposed to happen. Containers are meant to be ephemeral, which means you constantly create and destroy containers. [create-ephemeral-containers](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers)

By creating your custom Image you would always have your desired packages available in future containers. To do so, you first need to create a `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update -y && apt -y install vim
```

In the same directory you then run `docker build .` which will install the package `vim` by adding a new layer to your new `Image`. At the end of the build you will be presented with a unique image-id like:

`Successfully built 895449f549db`

Now you can spawn a new container from the previous id which contains all your installed packages.

```
docker run -ti 895449f549db bash
```

This is very basic stuff. I suggest you do some more reading like [getting started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)

Answer (score 0):

After some reading, I found  out the easiest solution to my noob question is that I used the `run` command to run an existing  container rather than the `start` command with `docker`. I know this is super noob but anyway I am writing the basic solution for posterity.

command to create the container :

`docker run -it --name=Ubuntu <image>`

Assigning a suitable name(in this case Ubuntu) to easily spot the container when using lots of container.

To run the same container later:

`docker start -i Ubuntu`

Another way is to commit the container instance into an image and run that image later. It will preserve all the installed softwares in the new image.

```
docker commit container_ID  newimagename 

docker run -it newimagename
```

As shown here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33956387/7787654

Comment: Using commit is a bad idea. Building the container should be scripted (Dockerfile, etc...).